# Is it possible to split transaction fees across multiple payers?

Tags: transactions, fees

I'm sure the answer is no but I want to have this confirmed.

Is it possible to split transaction fees across multiple payers?

Bonus question: is it possible to partially pay the fee to mint a Metaplex NFT.
For example, if the end cost is around 50 cents, can I have my treasury pay 30 cents of the costs and the minter (end user) pay the rest?

If it's not possible, is there a chance it ever becomes possible in the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are two parts to this question

**(1) Base Tx fee**

There is a base fee for every transaction (0.000005 SOL). I assume this is roughly how it works with wallet adapters:

```
tx.feePayer = wallet.publicKey
tx = await wallet.signTransaction(tx)
```

Currently `feePayer` is just a **single** pubkey.

**(2) Tx incurred fees**

Then there are fees incurred depending on the constituent instructions within the transaction. These fees are usually account creation fees. I.e. paying for NFT account storage space.

For NFT mint your transaction would probably include something like a `createMetaplexNFT(payer, ...)` instruction, wherein **a single** `payer` specifies who is going to pay for the account storage/minting fees.

**Re: bonus question**:

To achieve this you could

1. Simple method: in every NFT minting transaction, append an additional instruction that transfers SOL from your treasury to the user. Be wary that the user has to pay for the mint, since the payer will be the owner of the NFT (I might be wrong here and better to check the minting instruction source code for whether there is a distinction between payer and owner; in case you wanted the treasury to be the payer).
2. Complex method: Create your own Solana program and make an instruction wrapper of `createMetaplexNFT(payer, ...)`. I.e. your program instruction should do a CPI call to metaplex NFT mint in addition to doing SOL transfer from treasury to user. This method is more suitable if you want more customisation of the logic.

Comment: This is it. Thanks 